# string join to build ldap string

Tags: c#

I have stored my LDAP OUs in sql table and I need to retreive these values to build my LDAP string. let say my list has values like US, NY, RICHMOND, COM
How can I do that using string.join so my string will be like 
`OU=US,OU=NY,OU=RICHMOND,OU=COM`. With my code below `OU=US` comes out like `US=OU`

```
Differentlistnode.Add(child.InnerText);

string ldapstring = string.Join("=ou,", Differentlistnode.Select(x=> x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

Comment: _ou=_ and then the list of ous

Comment: @AndrewMorton Aside from the markdown being labeled `code` I've found nothing that limits it's use to code.  Everything I've read implies "Make the question easier to understand", which in my opinion applies to expected vs. actual output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118365/discussion-between-dckuehn-and-andrew-morton).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could append the ou= inside select and use join to insert the comma

```
string.Join(",", Differentlistnode.Select(x => "OU=" + x.ToString()));
```